# What should we expect the ratio of the area of $f(S)$ to the area of $S$ to be for small objects $S$ centred at $(a,b)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f: \mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is a differentiable function. The best linear approximation of $f$ near $(a,b)$ is the affine function
$$T(x,y) = Df(a,b)(x-a, y-b) + f(a,b),$$
where $Df(a,b)$ is the $2\times2$ Jacobian matrix for $f$ at $(a,b)$.

(A) What should we expect the ratio of the area of $f(S)$ to the area of $S$ to be for small objects centred at $(a,b)$?

I am having a lot of trouble learning this concept. I do not understand what this is supposed to mean or what it is supposed to do. If someone could elaborate and clearly explain the reasoning behind this concept and the problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What happens to the area if you use $T$ itself instead of $f$?  The unit square maps to a parallelogram.  What is the area of the parallelogram?

Comment: @GEdgar Please read the question.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the question is that, for $S$ small, the area of $f(S)$ should be fairly similar to that of $T(S)$. And $T$ is affine, i.e. $T=A+f(a,b)$ where $A=Df(a,b)$ is the Jacobian, so $T(S)$ and $A(S)$ have the same area (they differ by translation).

Now, if we consider a small rectangle $S$ spanned by multiples of the canonical unit vectors $t e_1=(t,0)$ and $r e_2=(0,r)$, then $A$ transforms the rectangle into a parallelogram $S'$, and the area of this parallelogram is 
$$\tag{1}
A(te_1)\times A(r e_2)=tr\,Ae_1\times Ae_2=tr\,\det A. 
$$
So the ratio between the areas is 
$$\tag{2}
\frac{rt\,\det A}{rt}=\det A=\det Df(a,b). 
$$

To see the equality in $(1)$, not that
$$
Ae_1\times Ae_2=\begin{vmatrix}i& j & k\\ a_{11}& a_{21}&0\\ a_{12}&a_{22}&0\end{vmatrix}=a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=\det A.
$$

Comment: 'The point of the question is that, for $S$ small, the area of $f(S)$ should be fairly smilier to that of T(S).' Please give more background on this. I think I'm struggling to understand this because I lack the background knowledge assumed by the question. I do have background knowledge on the tangent plane and using it as an approximation to a function at a point. I also understand that, in an open disk entered at a point $(a,b)$, the tangent plane is a good approximation for the function $f(a,b)$, since $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$. Please build off of here.

Comment: In other words, how does this question relate to my knowledge as represented in the above comment?

Comment: Please someone?